# How to get only State Name (administrative_area_level_1) in Google Geocoding API

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I am developing an android application which has to implement the Google Geocode to get the state name (administrative_area_level_1). 
To get it, I've already able to get the longitude and latitude using the usual LocationManager in Android. Now what I need to do is just to pass the lat and long on to Google Geocode url like this:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452

In result, url above shows (JSON and XML) with several results and types of location.
What I want to achieve is to get the name of administrative_area_level_1 (state name) value of the first result shown in the JSON.

How can I achieve this? Is it possible to achieve this?
Please help, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code to get the state name from google api .

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
         String Status = jsonObj.getString("status");
        if (Status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) 
        {
           JSONArray Results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
           JSONObject zero = Results.getJSONObject(0);
           JSONArray address_components = zero.getJSONArray("address_components");

           for (int i = 0; i < address_components.length(); i++) 
           {
               JSONObject zero2 = address_components.getJSONObject(i);
               String long_name = zero2.getString("long_name");
               JSONArray mtypes = zero2.getJSONArray("types");
               String Type = mtypes.getString(0);

               if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("locality")) 
               {
                  City = long_name;


                  Log.e("current city name:","city:"+City);


               } 
               else
               {
                   if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_2")) 
                   {
                      County = long_name;
                   } 
                   else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_1")) 
                   {
                     State = long_name;


                     Log.e("current city name:","administrative_area_level_1:"+State);
                   } 
                   else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("country")) 
                   {
                     Country = long_name;
                   } 
               }
           }
        }
```

Comment: I'm going to try it, but may be quite long to confirm as I've just got the lat long, I need to configure the geocode first. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi, I've done trying your code but my state name always null. Checking my logcat shows the java.lang.nullpointerexception in the line of the url: JSONObject jsonObj = parser_Json.getJSONFromUrl("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocodejson?latlng="+ lat + "," + lng + "&sensor=true");
Do you have any thought on it?

Comment: Thanks for help, It works finally after several modifications.